# converting float to LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi

So I have, let's say

```
float x;
```

and I have

```
 LPCWSTR message=L"X is";
```

how can I create a LPCWSTR with the message

> "X is [x]"

?

Comment: Do you have access to the STL? You could use a wstringstream

Comment: @pstrjds: Pedantry -- streams are not part of the STL.  They are part of the Standard Library.

Comment: @JohnDibling - I stand corrected. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`wstringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float x = 0.1f;
    std::wstringstream s;
    s << L"X is " << x;
    std::wstring ws = s.str();
    std::wcout << ws << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

and create an `LPCWSTR` from it if required, or just use the `std::wstring`.

Comment: how would one create a LPCWSTR from the wstring?

Comment: @Ameoo, can you not just use `ws.c_str()` ?

Answer (score 5):

You would use something like `wsprintf()` or its more modern (and safe) replacement, such as `StringCbPrintf()`.

The point is that you can't just "convert", you need to *build* the string, character by character, that is the textual representation of the floating-point number.

Comment: Or you can use `swprintf` which is standard and in recent compilers takes a buffer size parameter so it's also safe.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `_vsnwprintf`

headers

> `<wchar.h> <stdarg.h>`

[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273401%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)